# Project Euler #3 Explanation

Tags: javascript

The following code was posted on theodin project.com as a solution to [Project euler's question 3](https://projecteuler.net/problem=3) in javascript. Could you explain why there is no checkking to see if n is prime? How does this work? Also, why do they divide n by the factor and change its value... because once you up the value of the factor by 1 don't you want the same original number?

```
var factor = 2;

function getPrime(number) {
    while(number != factor) {
        if (number % factor === 0) {
            number = number / factor;
            factor = 2;
        } else {factor += 1}
    }

//        console.log(factor);

    function writePrime(factor) {
        return factor;
    }

    console.log(writePrime(factor))

}
 getPrime(600851475143);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dividing `number` by `factor` makes sense because otherwise you would find the first factor an infinite amount of times, so you want that factor gone, hence you divide.

Increasing `factor` makes sense too, since that's what you check for. And you need to check for 2, then 3, then 5, etc.

And you don't have to check whether `factor` even is a prime number because if it is not, `number` won't be dividable by it since it has already been divided by the prime factors of `factor`. (If a number is not dividable by 2, it won't be dividable by 4 either, and you don't even reach 4 until you divided by 2 until `number` is no longer dividable by 2.) Checking if `number` is dividable by `factor` is presumably also faster than checking if `factor` is a prime number.

However, `var factor = 2;` should be done inside the function, otherwise a consecutive call might cause an infinite loop.
If I'm not mistaken, `factor = 2;` can be omitted entirely inside the loop (speeding up the function), since you only need to "not increase" the factor.
Also `writePrime` does nothing at all and I suggest returning the value instead of printing it.

```
function getPrime(number)
{
    var factor = 2;
    while(number != factor)
    {
        if(number % factor === 0)
        {
            number = number / factor;
        }
        else
        {
            factor++;
        }
    }
    return factor;
}

getPrime(600851475143);
```